# Position a background image off the edge of a ul/li item

Tags: css, image, background, html-lists

I have a background image that I'd like to position just off the edge of my ul li item.

**Image**

[image: Arrow on UL LI item]

I guess you can see what I'm trying to do, position that little right pointing arrow off the egde, similar to the one at the top that points downwards. (The lime will be changed for the same colour as the arrow, but at the mo I have put a contrasting colour so the arrow can actually be seen)

**CSS**

```
body ul#main_navigation li li:hover > a, body ul#main_navigation li li.over > a
{
     background-image:url(/images/nav_arrow_right.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center right;
     background-color: #0F0;
     color: #FFF;
}
```

**Desired result**

[image]

EDIT: I have managed to get the arrow positioned correctly, however it is cutting off... how can I make it not cut off anything that is outside of the item?

Comment: Do you mean off the right edge?

Comment: @Francesca what exactly do you want with right arrow do you wanna drag from right side to left sidev  or what ??

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean I'd like that arrow to be a few pixels to the right so that it hangs off the edge of the lime item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Francesca so you can play with positioning you can set the `background-position`where do you want the arrow image that will go there............

I am giving you some rough idea below i don't have your much code....

```
body ul#main_navigation li li:hover > a, body ul#main_navigation li li.over > a
{
     background-image:url(/images/nav_arrow_right.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:center 10px;
     background-color: #0F0;
     color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: actually i just gave the roughly idea to her where she wants to she can define the value and achieve the results am i right i think.

Comment: This doesn't work. 10px makes it sit in the centre, -10px makes it vanish altogether, and every other value I have tried doesn't achieve anything near what I want. In fact it only seems to adjust the positioning of it up and down. Not left and right. I tried the same with center, top, left and right and got nothing correct.

Comment: @FrancescaHaselden can you show us the complete HTML markup demo of your problem..........

Comment: @FrancescaHaselden can you place the image of your desired result i think that would help us to sort out the bug...........

Comment: @FrancescaHaselden u can discuss with here :- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15567/css

Comment: as per your desired result image you will have to make a demo than we will able to sort out your problem.....